# Creating a model instance

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have two Models, (`Doctor` & `Patient`), the `Doctor` model is the *parent* model, How can I make the `Service_doctor` field an instance of the `Doctor`'s model so that I can get the `Doctor`'s name into the `Patient`'s model using **for loop** in the HTML Template. This is what am trying to mean;

**models.py**

```py
class Doctor(models.Model):
        Doctor_Name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

        def __str__(self):
        return self.Doctor_Name

class Patient(models.Model):
        Name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        Telephone = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
        Service_doctor = models.ForeignKey(Doctor, on_delete=CASCADE)
        def __str__(self):
        return self.Doctor_Name
```

**views.py**

```
def Newpatient(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':         

        Name = request.POST.get('Name')
        Telephone = request.POST.get('Telephone')
        Service_doctor = request.POST.get('Service_doctor')

        formdata = Patient(Name=Name, Telephone=Telephone, Service_doctor=Service_doctor)
        formdata.save()

        return render(request, 'Adm.html')
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This will create a new record under patient:

```
dr = Doctor.object.filter(id = pk)

patient = Patient(
       name = 'John Doe'
       telephone = '123456786'
       service_doctor = dr
       )
```

Comment: Lopez,  Thanks for your answer, but it made me ask this:-  do I need to declare the (pk) somewhere? because I think this cannot work if primary key is not declared .

Comment: the primary key was an example, you can use whatever you need in order to instantiate Doctor, in a project I'm working I filter by an order and current user

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the `request.user` to set the `Service_doctor` as the one that is currently in instance:

```py
def Newpatient(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':         
        Name = request.POST.get('Name')
        Telephone = request.POST.get('Telephone')
        Service_doctor = request.user

        formdata = Patient(Name=Name, Telephone=Telephone, Service_doctor=Service_doctor)
        formdata.save()

        return render(request, 'Adm.html')
```